# The program '[8636] .exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, command-line-arguments

I have the main() function as -

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{         
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
        cout<<argv[i];

    getch();
}
```

But I'm unable to type any inputs. The console window closes as soon as I press a key.

The input I want to give is -

```
-source filename -tag tagname -m minutes
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()` also flush `std::cout` after your loop (e.g. `cout << endl;`)

Comment: What is `getch`? Where is that function defined? Is it part of the CURSES library? Why aren't you using, e.g. `std::cin`? Also, `main` always returns `int`, never `void`.

Answer (score 0):

[getch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235446.aspx) is deprecated, accordingly to the page I have posted, so use [_getch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) instead.

Moreover, there is no way to enter inputs when running the application. You shall call it with parameters, like:

```
my_app.exe -source filename -tag tagname -m minutes
```

in the command line for Windows, or

```
./my_appl -source filename -tag tagname -m minutes
```

for Linux

You can also pass the input parameters in the configuration menus:

- Visual C++: right-click on project in project manager -> properties and at Debug -> Command arduments

Comment: That doesn't answer the (implied) question, why the OP doesn't see the command line arguments printed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this on Windows or Linux? If you're doing this on Linux, after you compile the file, you run the file as the name of the file plus the command line arguments.  So your console window (assuming you're not using a mkfile) would look something like this;

gcc -o File File.cpp

File -source filename -tag tagname -m minutes

That being said, you don't use getch() for command line arguments. You use it for user driven event programming.

As for Windows, there's a couple ways to do it, with the simplest probably be using command prompt and typing the program's name with the command line arguments following.

Comment: Where do I find the  .exe file? I'm working with VS2005 in Windows

Comment: Do you know where you made the project directory? If so, open command prompt and type _cd directory/debug_ and the .exe will be located in there.

Comment: I did what you said. When I try to execute, it says the program cannot execute because pthreadVC2.dll is missing from my computer. But I had placed the dll file in Windows\System32 folder

Comment: place the .dll in the same folder the .exe is.